# Stop bot sending multiple requests quickly. PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bots

I am having an issue with someone who keeps exploiting my betting site with a bot. He is able to (presumably) use a bot to press the "Roll" button multiple times very quickly and get the same roll numbers.

The roll button using a function to work. Here is this function:

```
var rolling=false;
var lastBet=(Date.now()-<?php echo $settings['rolls_mintime']; ?>-1000);
function place(wager,multiplier,bot) {
  if ((rolling==false && (Date.now())>=(lastBet+<?php echo $settings['rolls_mintime']; ?>)) || bot==true) {
    rolling=true;
    lastBet=Date.now();
    $("#betBtn").html('ROLLING');
    if (bot!=true) _stats_content('my_bets');      
    $.ajax({
      'url': './content/ajax/place.php?w='+wager+'&m='+multiplier+'&hl='+under_over+'&_unique=<?php echo $unique; ?>',
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function(data) {
        if (data['error']=='yes') {
          if (data['data']=='too_small') alert('Error: Your bet is too small.');
          if (data['data']=='invalid_bet') alert('Error: Your balance is too small for this bet.');
          if (data['data']=='invalid_m') alert('Error: Invalid multiplier.');
          if (data['data']=='invalid_hl') alert('Error: Invalid under/over specifier.');
if (data['data']=='invalid_bts') alert('Using bots, tut tut.');
          if (data['data']=='too_big_bet') alert('Error: Your bet is too big. Currently max profit is set at: '+data['under']+' this represents 1% of the invested backroll.');
        }
        else {
          var result=data['result'];
          var win_lose=data['win_lose'];
          if (win_lose==1) winCeremonial();
          else shameCeremonial();
        }
```

This function then leads to the php file. Here is the header of it:

```
if (empty($_GET['_unique']) || mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"))==0) exit();

$playerinv=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`playcoins`,`time`, `ex`, `server_seed` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"));
$random = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
$setstring = $random;
mysql_query("UPDATE `players` SET `string` = '$setstring' WHERE `id`=$playerinv[id] LIMIT 1");
$playersec=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `string` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"));

if ($setstring != $playersec['string']) {
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'yes','data'=>'invalid_bts'));
exit();
}

$newSeed=generateServerSeed();
mysql_query("UPDATE `players` SET `server_seed`='$newSeed' WHERE `id`=$playerinv[id] LIMIT 1");

$settings=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `system` LIMIT 1"));

$player=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['_unique'])."' LIMIT 1"));
$player['server_seed_']=$player['server_seed'];
$player['server_seed']=(double)substr($player['server_seed'],27);
```

As you can see from the beginning, I tried to create a work around by generating a random string exclusive to that one run ($setstring), storing it and then comparing it against itself. However somehow he managed to run it fast enough to get past this as-well.

$newseed is the variable which has the roll number. As you can see a new one is usually generated each run-time. I'm generally confused as to how he can do this, as I thought each php file runs separately.

Can anyone help provide some insight or solutions! I have been suggested transaction encapsulation for example, but not sure how to implement. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: bot beat with CAPTCHA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this attack works because of multi-threading. Firing many requests will make your code behave erratically because of random interleaving.

A simple example is a bank:

Let's say you want to deduct $20 from your account:

```
$amount = q("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = $account_id");
q("UPDATE accounts SET amount = $amount - 20 WHERE id = $account_id");
```

If you start with $100, and you run this code twice you expect to end up with $60. But, if the thread interleaving happens between the select and update call both threads will read $100 so they will both update to $80.

You're thinking in the right direction with `$setstring` but you need something more powerful. You need to look at locking.

```
$lock = acquire_lock("foo");
$amount = q("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = $account_id");
q("UPDATE accounts SET amount = $amount - 20 WHERE id = $account_id");
release_lock($lock);
```

Locks can be implemented in many ways. PHP even has some special functions and extensions for it. The simplest way is to use a file lock.

```
function acquire_lock($name) {
    return fopen($name, "rw");
}
function release_lock($lock) {
    fclose($lock);
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, I believe it should work in theory :p

You can test this with a script that does:

```
$lock = acquire_lock("foo");
sleep(30); // do nothing for 30 seconds
release_lock($lock);
```

And then try to run another script that also tries to acquire the `foo` lock. It should have to wait 30 seconds.

Comment: I'll try this now. Thank you it's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. What purpose does "rw" serve in the first function?

Comment: Check http://php.net/fopen it opens the file in read and write mode. I think just `w` might be enough. Maybe just `r` also works. This is the part I'm not sure about and requires testing ;)

Comment: isnt is this the same with the concept of debouncing?

Comment: debouncing is like locking but the difference is that it happens on the server, and when it comes to security that makes all the difference. So yea, you're basically implementing a debounce on the server.

Comment: ahhh i see, debouncing for client-side, locking for server-side. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

you can also implement a [simple debouncer using javascript](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) in your roll button, or an easy to implement [google captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

Comment: Debounce would stop you for clicking the button, but not from sending the requests. Captcha might be too invasive.

Comment: i think thats what OP really wants, because if he wants to have a 1 time click on the roll button, WHY NOT DISABLE IT AFTER CLICKING??

Comment: because the attacker probably isn't clicking the button. He's just firing the requests, skipping the button completely. You can open a JavaScript console and do: `for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1){ $.ajax(/**/) }` to fire 100 requests. If the attacker is smarter he will not even use JavaScript to attack to get around the connections-per-domain limit.

Comment: but he said: "I tried to create a work around by generating a random string exclusive to that one run ($setstring)" isnt he creating it within the page that sends the request? If he did that, then the attacker might be boting within the program itself

Comment: or the attacker can generate the strings too, so he can send it automatically?

Comment: The `$setstring` doesn't really work. It might reduce the chance of a favorable interleaving but it doesn't prevent the attack completely. If your script has 10 statements, adding a 2 statement `$setstring` check will reduce the chance of a favorable interleaving by about 8%. How many of those will you need till you feel safe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75447/discussion-between-ceeee-and-halcyon).