# PHP locking not working. Can't figure out why

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, locking, bots

Hi guys I'm following up from my question [Acquire_lock() not working. Bot still sending requests quickly. PHP + AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710997/acquire-lock-not-working-bot-still-sending-requests-quickly-php-ajax) which I haven't been able to get an answer for.

I've simplified everything and have three files

- abc.txt
- file1.php
- file2.php

All in the same directory and the contents of both php files are the same:

```
<?php 
$x = fopen("/var/www/abc.txt", "w"); 
if (flock($x, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) { 
print "No problems, I got the lock, now I'm going to sit on it."; 
while (true) 
    sleep(5); 
} else { 
print "Didn't quite get the lock. Quitting now. Good night."; 
} 
fclose($x); 
?>
```

Yet when I load either of them, I get the second print message: "Didn't quite get the lock. Quitting now. Good night.".

Anyone have any idea, either to this question or the former as to what's going on? Literally at my wits end with this.

Thank you as always.

Comment: I dont see where the problem is, except that your code is going into an infinite loop after locking (which i assume you made it intentionally to test the lock?) I tested this on my local server and file1.php kept looping while file2.php displayed the second message immediately. what exactly is the requested behaviour?

Comment: @Tarek I'm just trying to figure out how locking works. What I want, ultimately, is if you run the 1st and then the 2nd script, the 2nd script will wait untill the 1st has finished. As soon as the first script finishes, the second one will acquire the lock and finish the execution..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the php script to not exit then you would want a blocking lock.

[flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#refsect1-function.flock-parameters) documentation says you can do it by specifying third parameter. Also removing **LOCK_NB** might help.

```
<?php 
$x = fopen("/var/www/abc.txt", "w"); 
if (flock($x, LOCK_EX, 1)) { 
    print "No problems, I got the lock, now I'm going to sit on it."; 
    // wait for 5 seconds
    sleep(5);
    // Release the lock now so that next script is executed
    flock($x , LOCK_UN);
} else { 
    print "Didn't quite get the lock. Quitting now. Good night."; 
} 
fclose($x); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's going on in your script:

1) You code is going into an infinite loop `while(true)` and it is never reaching the fclose() statement at the end.

2) I tested both files on my local server: File1.php kept looping while the second file2.php gave the file is locked messaged immediately (which means the first file locked correctly). I tried refreshing both files afterwards and they both failed the lock test.

If you are using PHP> 5.3.2 then you have to unlock the file manually:

> The automatic unlocking when the file's resource handle is closed was
>   removed. Unlocking now always has to be done manually.
>   [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

If you are using an older version of PHP, then the script will unlock the file once the script is done executing, since you are going into an infinite loop, the script is never done and therefore the file is never unlocked.

Also, even if you stop the script from running in your browser window, the process php-cgi.exe related to that script remains running and has to be terminated manually from the task manager (I verified that myself)

Solution:

1)
To fix this issue and make the script wait for the lock, you need to make sure first that the script actually stops gracefully by removing the infinite loop:

Here is a script that will lock the file for 30 seconds (loop removed):

```
<?php 
$x = fopen("/var/www/abc.txt", "w"); 
if (flock($x, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) { 
print "No problems, I got the lock, now I'm going to sit on it."; 
sleep(30);
fclose($x); // it is good practice to always close even your PHP <5.3.2
} 
else { 
print "Didn't quite get the lock. Quitting now. Good night."; 
} 

?>
```

2) If you are on a linux machine, you can use the LOCK_NB flag to determine whether the file is locked or not. The usage of LOCK_NB should be like this:

```
while ( ! flock($f, LOCK_NB) ) 
{
    sleep(1);
}
```

this will force the script to check every second for the lock and wait for the other script to finish.

3) use `flock($fp, LOCK_UN)` to explicitly remove the lock when you are done instead of fclose();
In summary, this is how your code should look like:

```
<?php 
$x = fopen("/var/www/abc.txt", "w");
while(!flock($x,LOCK_NB)
    sleep(1);

if (flock($x, LOCK_EX,true)) { 
print "No problems, I got the lock, now I'm going to sit on it."; 
sleep(30);
fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else { 
print "Didn't quite get the lock. Quitting now. Good night."; 
} 
fclose($x); 
?>
```

Comment: I've copied #3 into file1.php and file2.php and all I get when I run them is a blank screen. Is this normal? I am using Linux.

Comment: no it should display the first message. Unfortunately i dont have access to a linux machine right now to test and debug my code.

Comment: I tried #1 as-well in both files and when I loaded file1.php for the first time it showed me "Didn't quite get the lock. Quitting now. Good night" and the same for file2.php if that helps.

Comment: @Ben try adding true to the wouldblock argument in flock, i edited my code to show you how. The suggestion came from the other answer here.

Comment: I had to chmod 777 /var/www/abc.txt and then it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So strange as I've been reading up everywhere and no-where mentions about the file having appropriate permissions. Maybe it's implied, idk.

Comment: when i was testing, i had to give permission for the IIS user. I assumed you already did that and focused on the code. anw Glad it worked. Goodluck